# using perl to create a simple calculator

Tags: perl, unix

I need to design a simple calculator in Perl called ex1.pl with only `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` functions. Below is what I have.

```
while (@ARGV>0) {
    if ($_=~m/(\d+)\s(.)\s(\d+)/) {
        if ($2 == "+") {
            print "$1 + $3\n";
        }   
        elsif ($2 == "-") {
            print "$1 - $3\n";
        }   
        elsif ($2 == "*") {
            print "$1 * $3\n";
        }   
        elsif ($2 == "/") {
            if ($3 == 0 ) { 
                print "$1 cannot be divided by 0\n";
            }   
            else {
                print "$1 / $3\n";
            }   
        }   
        else {
            print "operator not identified\n";
        }
    }   
    else {
        print "syntax error\n";
    }   
}
```

For example, if I type `./ex1.pl 5 + 2`, It keeps reporting errors that

```
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at line 4
```

until I press ctrl + c.  Can anyone help me identify where I did wrong??

Comment: your regex match on line 4 is matching against the variable `$_` but you never put anything in `$_`.  You could use `shift` to grab the arguments one-by-one from `@ARGV`, but your code structure kind of assumes the values and the operator are all together in one string. You could dispense with the while loop altogether and do something like `$_ = "@ARGV"`, which will put all the values from `@ARGV` into one string with a single space between each value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop `while(@ARGV>0)` doesn't assign to `$_` on which the regex match is done, so nothing is matched and the code goes to `else`. Also, `@ARGV` is never emptied so the code is in the infinite loop.

The rest of the code is syntactically correct but has to be rewritten, since it iterates over words in input while the regex is written to process the whole of it. Either the processing needs to take each argument in turn, or the command line need be assembled into a string, for that regex.

Further comments on the code in the question are posted further below.

Let me offer a different approach

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my ($n1, $op, $n2) = @ARGV;

my $re_oper = qr{^(?:\+|-|\*|/)$};  #/

usage() if @ARGV != 3
    or not looks_like_number($n1) or not looks_like_number($n2)
    or $op !~ $re_oper;

my %calculate = ( 
    '+' => sub { return $_[0] + $_[1] },
    '-' => sub { return $_[0] - $_[1] },
    '*' => sub { return $_[0] * $_[1] },
    '/' => sub {
        die "Can't divide by zero" if $_[1] == 0;
        return $_[0] / $_[1] 
    },
);

say $calculate{$op}->($n1, $n2);

sub usage { 
    say STDERR 
        "Usage: $0 number operator number\n",
        "The \"operator\" is one of +,-,\\*,/\n",
        "Note that multiplication (*) must be escaped at command line";
    exit;
}
```

The arguments are copied and checked for errors using `looks_like_number` from [Scalar::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Scalar/Util.html), and a regex. I prepare the regex pattern using the [`qr` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) so that it is specified separately, what makes testing, maintenance, and expansion easier.

Then we define a hash with anonymous subroutines as values (they are *code references*, see item **4.** in [Making references in perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References)), often called a [*dispatch table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table#Perl_implementation). Thus  there is no need for a cascading `if-elsif` series: For a given key (the operator) the corresponding value is dereferenced and that subroutine runs.

The arguments are checked in one statement for brevity, but this is better done one by one so to be able to report to the user the exact error made (and quote input that caused it).

---

A few more specifics on the posted code

- Captured pattern for the operator need be tested using *string* comparison, what is done with `eq` operator, not with `==`. See these [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).
  So `if ($2 eq '+')` etc
- A regex match is by default done against the [`$_` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables), the default for many things in Perl.  So there is no need to write `if ($_ =~ /.../)` but just `if (/.../)`. This is far clearer to read what justifies the (implicit) use of `$_`
- Regex pattern `\d` matches all kinds of digits, Unicode included. Better use `[0-9]`
- The pattern `\s` allows for *one* "whitespace" character.  If you combine the command line arguments into a string by `$input = join ' ', @ARGV;` (so to use regex on it) then that is fine. But it is still safer to allow for more spaces with `\s+`.
- The `.` in regex matches any *one* character. This limits possible future expansion of the script, for example to raise to power `**` (etc). Consider allowing any characters between numbers, what is feasible as they are delimited on the command line by space.
- The pattern used for numbers matches only positive integers (while accidentally allowing the first one to be negative if a minus precedes it). The code above takes care of this by using `looks_like_number`, which utilizes all that Perl can do to recognize a number.

---

***The question's original version** had `while (<>)` for the loop, and the answer started with this*:

The ["diamond" operator (`<>`)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) reads from files submitted on the command line

> Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line.

so your input `5 + 2` is taken to be filenames `5` and `+` and `2`, and such files don't exist.

There is more complexity to this operator, about which one can read in the documentation.

The command line arguments can be accessed in [@ARGV](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#ARGV), so the simplest solution is to replace the `while (<>)` with `foreach (@ARGV)` and then process term by term.

Comment: Hi, zdim! Thank you! You are right! I modified <> to @ARGV and updated my post, but it still reports error

Comment: @张剑桥  See the end of my answer -- need `foreach (@ARGV)`, not `while`.

Comment: Hi zdim! I have tried this one, and this time it reports three "syntax error"

Comment: @张剑桥  Also: normally you don't want to change the question to incorporate answers -- it makes those answers invalid :).  All this content is hoped to be useful for people who come later, so best leave the question as it was (apart from minor corrections or edits)

Comment: @张剑桥  Again: you need `foreach (@ARGV)`, **not `while`**.  The way you have it right now nothing is assigned to `$_`, on which the match is done.

Comment: I have used foreach(@ARGV), and that is when three "syntax error" jumped out

Comment: The remaining stay the same, I just modified the first line to "foreach(@ARGV){"

Comment: @张剑桥 Alright, that was the most glaring error.  Now clean up your indentation, put closing curlies on a separate line, etc -- then you'll spot the other errors.

Comment: Sorry zdim, it seems the same, it couldn't identify the three arguments I want it to