# Taking operators as argument variables

Tags: perl

Hi I am trying to create a simple calculator with only four operators `+, -, /` and `*` and for some reason my implementation doesn't work.

I have seen several working implementations (including some that deserve an award for most obfuscated) however what I am curious to know is why *doesn't* the following work?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $num1 = $ARGV[0];
my $num2 = $ARGV[2];

my $operator = $ARGV[1];

print "$operator \n";

if($operator == '-')
{
  $num3 = $num1 - $num2;
  print "$num1 - $num2 = $num3\n";
} 
elsif($operator == "+")
{
  $num3 = $num1 + $num2;
  print "$num1 + $num2 = $num3\n";
}
elsif($operator == "/")
{
  $num3 = $num1 / $num2;
  print "$num1 / $num2 = $num3\n";
}
elsif($operator == "*")
{
  $num3 = $num1 * $num2;
  print "$num1 * $num2 = $num3\n";
}
```

Also, the command `./expr.pl 7 * 2` returns the following: `03.bellpaper.doc` which is just unfathomable.

Comment: Don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Also see [using perl to create a simple calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50597544/4653379)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always start your files with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

In your case that first results in

```
Global symbol "$num3" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $num3"?) at script line 14.
```

After adding the missing `my $num3` declaration, we get

```
Argument "-" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at script line 13.
```

That happens because the `==` operator is numeric equality. It converts both operands to a number, which (if you don't enable warnings) silently gives `0` for invalid strings. That's why `($operand == '-')` ends up doing `0 == 0`, which is of course true.

To compare strings, you need to use `eq`:

```
if ($operand eq '-')
```

See also [*Relational Operators* in `perldoc perlop`](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Relational-Operators).

The problem with `./expr.pl 7 * 2` is that `*` is a wildcard that your shell expands to a list of all files in the current directory. Your program will be invoked as `./expr.pl 7 03.bellpaper.doc expr.pl whatever-else-is-in-the-current-directory 2`.

To prevent that, you need to quote it, e.g. with `./expr.pl 7 '*' 2` or `./expr.pl 7 "*" 2` or `./expr.pl 7 \* 2`.

---

Other notes:

- `$operand` is the wrong name. It's an operator. The two numbers are the operands.
- The manual assignments from `$ARGV[...]` can be merged together into a single list assignment: `my (...) = @ARGV;`
- The `print` statements in each block are almost identical. We can pull them out as `print "$num1 $operator $num2 = $num3\n"` (after making sure `$num3` is actually set).

That gives us:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($num1, $operator, $num2) = @ARGV;

print "$operator\n";

my $num3;
if ($operator eq '-') {
    $num3 = $num1 - $num2;
} elsif ($operator eq '+') {
    $num3 = $num1 + $num2;
} elsif ($operator eq '/') {
    $num3 = $num1 / $num2;
} elsif ($operator eq '*') {
    $num3 = $num1 * $num2;
}

if (defined $num3) {
    print "$num1 $operator $num2 = $num3\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestions, I have made the edits necessary to the functioning of the program - do you know why I might be receiving such a strange output when I use exclusively the `*` operator?

Comment: @DavideLorino You are passing your arguments through the shell, and `*` is a special character in shells (specifically a glob). The easiest way to avoid this is to quote operators when passing them: `'*'`

Comment: Maybe you should mention using a dispatch table?

Comment: @ikegami Eh, I thought about it, but figured it was probably too many advanced concepts for someone who's still trying to get string comparison to work.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, however the command ./expr.pl 7 * 2 returns the following: 03.bellpaper.doc which is just unfathomable.

`*` is a shell glob. Your shell is replacing `*` with the names of every file in the current directory. The arguments to your program are `7`, then a lot of filenames, then `2`. The first of those filenames gets printed by your `print "$operand\n"` line, and then since `$operand` doesn't match any of the things you're checking for, nothing else happens.

The way around this is simply to put quotes around the `*`, or to take input some other way than the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I am doing those kind of things, I would make an integer variable called choice that gets passed into the methods. And in the method I would have if and else if statements to interpret the argument. For example: 0 = +, 1 = -, 2 = / and 3 = *

Comment: 1. Why an integer? Passing the operator directly as a string works just as well and is much easier to debug / maintain. 2. This doesn't solve OP's problem. How do you convert the operator into a number?